# Remove objects from list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following list -

```
public class edgeData
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string target { get; set; }
}

var edgeList = new List<edgeData>();
var linkCount = 1;
```

I want to remove an `edgeData` entry from `edgeList` when the source *collectively* occurs less than or equal to `linkCount`.

For example build up my edgeData -

```
var newEdge = new edgeData();
newEdge.source = "James";
newEdge.target = 1;
edgeList.Add(newEdge);

var newEdge = new edgeData();
newEdge.source = "Greg";
newEdge.target = 2;
edgeList.Add(newEdge);

var newEdge = new edgeData();
newEdge.source = "James";
newEdge.target = 3;
edgeList.Add(newEdge);
```

Then process to remove entries that occur less or equal to `linkCount`-

```
public List<edgeData> RemoveLinks(List<edgeData>() edgeList, int linkCount)
{
    var updatedEdgeData = new List<edgeData>();

    // logic

    return updatedEdgeData;
}
```

So in the example the entry containing "Greg" as the source would be removed because he has occurred only once which is equal to the linkCount.

I tried doing this with a for loop however this got incredibly ugly pretty quickly and believe Linq is the best option however how can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, your code will not compile, you can't assign `int` value to string

Comment: Worth to mention your unique identifier of an item in the collection. I assume it's a  `source` property?

Comment: `edgeList.RemoveAll(edge => when_to_remove);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following

```
edgeList.GroupBy(x=>x.source)
                   .Where(x=>x.Count()>linkCount)
                   .SelectMany(x=>x)
                   .ToList();
```

You need to `Group` by the source and filter out the groups which has items less than the `linkCount`.

Please also note that according to OP, `edgeData.target` is a string, but your code shows it as number. Hopefully it is a typo.

**Update**

As Harald pointed out, if the size of group is huge, you could alternatively use,

```
edgeList.GroupBy(x=>x.source)
                   .Where(x=>x.Skip(linkCount).Any())
                   .SelectMany(x=>x)
                   .ToList()
```

Comment: If one of your groups has a million elements, and linkCount has a value of 5, why Count() all million elements? Use `Skip(5).Any()` instead.

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Thanks for pointing it out, have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove an edgeData entry from edgeList when the source collectively occurs less than or equal to linkCount.

I think you want in your end-result only those items from your input sequence that have a value of property `Source` that occurs more times in your sequence than `linkCount`.

So if `linkCount` equals 5, you only want to keep those records where there are at least five occurences of this `Source` in the input sequence.

For this we need to group your input into groups with the same value for `Source`. After that we only keep those groups that have more elements that `linkCount` in them:

```
IEnumerable<EdgeData> result = edgeList.GroupBy( edgeItem => edgeItem.Source)

    // keep only the groups with enough elements:
    .Where(group => group.Skip(linkCount).Any())

    // Ungroup, so we get a neat sequence
    .SelectMany(group => group);
```

The result of the GroupBy is a sequence of object where each object implements `IGrouping<string, EdgeData>`. This object is in itself a sequence of `EdgeData`, where every `Source` property has the same value. This value is in the `Key` of the IGrouping.

After making the groups, I keep only the groups that have more than linkCount items in them. I do this, by skipping the first LinkCount items of the sequence that the group is, and if there are any items left, then apparently the group has more than linkCount items.

I don't want to use Count(), because if your group has a zillion items, it would be a waste of processing power to count all those items, if you can stop counting after you've seen that there are more than linkCount.

The result of the Where is a sequence of `IGrouping<string, EdgeData>` To ungroup, we use `SelectMany`, which makes it a neat sequence of `EdgeData` again.

Comment: This is an excellent and informative answer with time put into it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just count the occurrnce of the names, then loop on the list and remove the one that you don't like (not enough connections)

```
        Dictionary<string, int> occurrence = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (edgeData edge in edgeList)
        {
            if (occurrence.ContainsKey(edge.source)) 
                occurrence[edge.source] += 1;
            else
                occurrence[edge.source] = 1;
        }

        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < edgeList.Count)
        {
            if (occurrence[edgeList[counter].source] < linkCount)
                edgeList.RemoveAt(counter);
            else 
                counter++;
        }
```